# Min Heap Extract 2 Smallest Element

Tags: c++

I have a minimum heap viz.

```
priority_queue<double, vector<double>, greater<double>> min_heap;
// push vector values to heap
for (const auto& e : rand)
    min_heap.push(e);
```

How can I get the 2 minimum values in this heap within `O(n)` time, by say using just one loop?

Regards.

Comment: Do you know how to use a priority_queue? Do you know what the various methods are and their various complexities?

Comment: @MooingDuck Not so much honestly. Never used them explicitly, now it seems I need to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in `O(logn)` time once your heap is formed. You can do it with a single pop and 2 queries.

```
int min1 = min_heap.top(); //get the minimum element
min_heap.pop(); //pop the minimum element from the heap
int min2 = min_heap.top(); //get the second minimum element(the new top)
min_heap.push(min1); //push the old 'top' to restore the heap to its old state
```

Looking at this will help : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue